# No external displays detected Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: multiple-monitors

What do I need to do to get an external display to show up under settings.

I have 2 monitors with multiple connection types (HDMI, DP) and no matter how I connect nothing shows up.

Help needed !

Comment: https://pastebin.com/4nYjjV9r

Comment: I think would be more helpful post only new lines when you connect a monitor